# Not Able to Add a RasterLayer to ArcGIS API For JavaScript Map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/KmrGd/8/) and let me know why I am not able to add the Raster Layer  Layer: **fishing_effort.tif (ID: 53)** into the Map?

```
var map;  
require([  
    "esri/map",  
    "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",  
    "dojo/ready",  
    "dojo/parser",  
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",  
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane"],  
function (  
Map, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer,  
ready, parser,  
BorderContainer, ContentPane) {  
    ready(function () {  
        parser.parse();  
        map = new Map("cpCenter", {  
            basemap: "topo",  
            center: [-9.113077, 0.759423],  
            zoom: 2  
        });  
        var layer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://renewablestoolbox.biol.sfu.ca/rorapp/rest/services/RORApp/MapServer/53")  
        map.addLayers([layer]);  
    });  
});
```

as you can see from the console I am getting 400 (Bad Request) error message but the layer is for sure at [This Url](http://renewablestoolbox.biol.sfu.ca/rorapp/rest/services/RORApp/MapServer/53)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to remove the reference to layer ID of `53`. The [ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html) is used to access an entire MapService and you are trying to point to a layer within that map service.

You can set that to be the only visible layer by doing this:

```
// make layer id of 53 the only visible layer
layer.setVisibleLayers([53]);
```